How to set an order quantity (qty) according to the syminfo.ticker dynamically
I am trying to set an order quantity (qty) according to the syminfo.ticker dynamically.
I have tried the following code, which doesn't fire any error, but the quantity set, when an order generated by my strategy is always 1 and doesn't change, when I am changing the chart ticker :

I have deleted the 'default_qty_value' from the script declaration statement.

I have added in my code :



qtyValue = syminfo.ticker == "OANDA:XAUUSD" ? 7 : syminfo.ticker == "OANDA:XAGUSD" ? 550 : syminfo.ticker == "OANDA:EURUSD" ? 225000 : syminfo.ticker == "OANDA:GBPUSD" ? 39000 : na

//  and in my strategy statement :
strategy.entry("Test", strategy.long, qty=qtyValue, comment="Test")


Would appreciate some expertise. thanks

syminfo.ticker is without the exchange prefix.

syminfo.ticker
Symbol name without exchange prefix, e.g. 'MSFT'.

You want to use syminfo.tickerid.
You can see that if you print them in a label.
//@version=5
strategy("My strategy", overlay=true)

s_ticker = syminfo.ticker
s_ticker_id = ticker.standard(syminfo.tickerid)

qtyValue = s_ticker_id == "OANDA:XAUUSD" ? 7 : s_ticker_id == "OANDA:XAGUSD" ? 550 : s_ticker_id == "OANDA:EURUSD" ? 225000 : s_ticker_id == "OANDA:GBPUSD" ? 39000 : na

if (barstate.isfirst)
    s = "syminfo.ticker: " + s_ticker + "\n"
    s := s + "syminfo.tickerid: " + s_ticker_id
    label.new(bar_index, high, s, textcolor=color.white)

//  and in my strategy statement :
strategy.entry("Test", strategy.long, qty=qtyValue, comment="Test")


